# Need explanation on MultiTexturing Negative coordinates

Tags: c++, opengl

Ok so I'm trying to figure out how this game works. It isn't created by me but I was intrigued at how it combines two textures, cuts out a circle and renders that portion to the screen depending on the character position.

Texture #1 is Map.bmp:

[image]

Texture #2 is the MM.bmp:
[image]

It then combines them to create a circular cut out within the Giant Map.
I've written an Emulator to do exactly the same commands as the game and it does cut it out the same way the game does.

The code is as follows:

Bitmap.h:

```
#ifndef BITMAP_H_INCLUDED
#define BITMAP_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

class Bitmap
{
    private:
        std::vector<std::uint8_t> Pixels;
        std::uint32_t width, height;
        std::uint16_t BitsPerPixel;

    public:
        Bitmap(const char* FilePath);

        inline std::uint16_t Bits()
        {
            return BitsPerPixel;
        }

        inline int Width() const
        {
            return width;
        }

        inline int Height() const
        {
            return height;
        }

        inline std::uint8_t* GetPixels()
        {
            return Pixels.data();
        }
};

#endif // BITMAP_H_INCLUDED
```

Bitmap.cpp:

```
#include "Bitmap.h"

Bitmap::Bitmap(const char* FilePath) : Pixels(0), width(0), height(0), BitsPerPixel(0)
{
    std::fstream hFile(FilePath, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    if (!hFile.is_open()) throw std::invalid_argument("Error: File Not Found.");

    hFile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    int Length = hFile.tellg();
    hFile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> FileInfo(Length);
    hFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(FileInfo.data()), 54);

    if(FileInfo[0] != 'B' && FileInfo[1] != 'M')
    {
        hFile.close();
        throw std::invalid_argument("Error: Invalid File Format. Bitmap Required.");
    }

    if (FileInfo[28] != 24 && FileInfo[28] != 32)
    {
        hFile.close();
        throw std::invalid_argument("Error: Invalid File Format. 24 or 32 bit Image Required.");
    }

    BitsPerPixel = FileInfo[28];
    width = FileInfo[18] + (FileInfo[19] << 8);
    height = FileInfo[22] + (FileInfo[23] << 8);
    std::uint32_t PixelsOffset = FileInfo[10] + (FileInfo[11] << 8);
    std::uint32_t size = ((width * BitsPerPixel + 31) / 32) * 4 * height;
    Pixels.resize(size);

    hFile.seekg (PixelsOffset, std::ios::beg);
    hFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(Pixels.data()), size);
    hFile.close();
}
```

and finally Main.cpp which emulates the game:

Main.cpp:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glext.h>
#include "Bitmap.h"



int Width = 781, Height = 591;
std::string Title = "Example";
std::string ClassName = "Example";

template<typename T, typename U>
bool xCast(T &FunctionDefinition, U FunctionAddress)
{
    return (FunctionDefinition = reinterpret_cast<T>(FunctionAddress));
}

void EnableOpenGL(HWND hwnd, HDC* hDC, HGLRC* hRC);
void DisableOpenGL (HWND hwnd, HDC hDC, HGLRC hRC);
GLuint LoadTexture(std::string FilePath, GLenum Target);
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hThisInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpszArgument, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX WndClass =
    {
        sizeof(WNDCLASSEX), CS_DBLCLKS, WindowProcedure,
        0, 0, GetModuleHandle(nullptr), LoadIcon(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION),
        LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW), HBRUSH(COLOR_WINDOW + 1),
        nullptr, ClassName.c_str(), LoadIcon (nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION)
    };

    if(RegisterClassEx(&WndClass))
    {
        HDC DC = nullptr;
        HGLRC HRC = nullptr;
        HWND WindowHandle = CreateWindowEx(0, ClassName.c_str(), Title.c_str(), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, Width, Height, nullptr, nullptr, GetModuleHandle(nullptr), nullptr);
        if(WindowHandle)
        {
            bool Quit = false;
            MSG msg = {nullptr};
            EnableOpenGL(WindowHandle, &DC, &HRC);
            ShowWindow(WindowHandle, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
            glViewport(0, 0, 765, 553);
            glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
            glLoadIdentity();
            glOrtho(0.0, 765, 553, 0.0, -1.0, 1.0);
            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
            glLoadIdentity();

            void (__stdcall *ptr_glActiveTextureARB) (GLenum texture);
            void (__stdcall *ptr_glMultiTexCoord2fARB) (GLenum target, GLfloat s, GLfloat t);
            xCast(ptr_glActiveTextureARB, wglGetProcAddress("glActiveTextureARB"));
            xCast(ptr_glMultiTexCoord2fARB, wglGetProcAddress("glMultiTexCoord2fARB"));


            GLint Map = LoadTexture("Map.bmp", GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            GLint MM = LoadTexture("MM.bmp", GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE);


            while(!Quit)
            {
                if (PeekMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
                {
                    if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                    {
                        Quit = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        TranslateMessage(&msg);
                        DispatchMessage(&msg);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    glPushMatrix();
                    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
                    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


                    //Combines the two textures and draws them to the screen.

                    glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
                    glScissor(550, 341, 154, 154);
                    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
                    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE);
                    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
                    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Map);
                    ptr_glActiveTextureARB(GL_TEXTURE1);
                    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE);
                    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, MM);
                    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_RGB, GL_REPLACE);
                    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_ALPHA, GL_MODULATE);
                    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SOURCE0_RGB, GL_PREVIOUS);
                    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_OPERAND0_RGB, GL_SRC_COLOR);
                    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                        glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
                        ptr_glMultiTexCoord2fARB(GL_TEXTURE0, 0, 1);
                        ptr_glMultiTexCoord2fARB(GL_TEXTURE1, -194.55215, 353.57529);
                        glVertex2f(355.44785, -141.57529);
                        ptr_glMultiTexCoord2fARB(GL_TEXTURE0, 0, 0);
                        ptr_glMultiTexCoord2fARB(GL_TEXTURE1, -212.4122, -194.13358);
                        glVertex2f(337.5878, 406.13358);
                        ptr_glMultiTexCoord2fARB(GL_TEXTURE0, 1, 0);
                        ptr_glMultiTexCoord2fARB(GL_TEXTURE1, 335.29663, -211.99362);
                        glVertex2f(885.29663, 423.99362);
                        ptr_glMultiTexCoord2fARB(GL_TEXTURE0, 1, 1);
                        ptr_glMultiTexCoord2fARB(GL_TEXTURE1, 353.15674, 335.71524);
                        glVertex2f(903.15674, -123.71524);
                    glEnd();
                    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SOURCE0_RGB, GL_TEXTURE);
                    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_OPERAND0_RGB, GL_SRC_COLOR);
                    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_RGB, GL_MODULATE);
                    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_ALPHA, GL_MODULATE);
                    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE);
                    ptr_glActiveTextureARB(GL_TEXTURE0);
                    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
                    glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);


                    glPopMatrix();
                    SwapBuffers(DC);
                    Sleep(1);
                }
            }
            DisableOpenGL(WindowHandle, DC, HRC);
            return msg.wParam;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


//Loads textures:
GLuint LoadTexture(std::string FilePath, GLenum Target)
{
    Bitmap Img(FilePath.c_str());
    GLuint ID = 0;
    glGenTextures(1, &ID);
    glBindTexture(Target, ID);
    glTexParameteri(Target, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, Target == GL_TEXTURE_2D ? GL_REPEAT : GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(Target, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, Target == GL_TEXTURE_2D ? GL_REPEAT : GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(Target, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(Target, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(Target, 0, Img.Bits() == 32 ? GL_RGBA : GL_RGB, Img.Width(), Img.Height(), 0, Img.Bits() == 32 ? GL_BGRA : GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, Img.GetPixels());
    return ID;
}    

void EnableOpenGL(HWND hwnd, HDC* hDC, HGLRC* hRC)
{
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
    int iFormat;
    *hDC = GetDC(hwnd);
    ZeroMemory(&pfd, sizeof(pfd));
    pfd.nSize = sizeof(pfd);
    pfd.nVersion = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = 24;
    pfd.cDepthBits = 16;
    pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;
    iFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(*hDC, &pfd);
    SetPixelFormat(*hDC, iFormat, &pfd);
    *hRC = wglCreateContext(*hDC);
    wglMakeCurrent(*hDC, *hRC);
}

void DisableOpenGL (HWND hwnd, HDC hDC, HGLRC hRC)
{
    wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
    wglDeleteContext(hRC);
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hDC);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
        {
            switch(wParam)
            {
                case VK_ESCAPE:
                    PostQuitMessage(0);
                    break;
            }
        }
        break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage (0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the output looks like:
[image]

What I want to know is, how does these negative coordinates work. For example, the glMultiTexCoord2fArb and the glVertex2f have coordinates that are out of bounds of the viewport. The viewport is 765x553. It also doesn't fit into the scissor area.

How does it figure out what portions of the texture to merge and is there a way I can do that myself so that I don't have to use the negative coords? In other words, how can I translate those negative coordinates into regular positive ones and figure out which portions of both textures are merged? I've written the example above to test and figure out how it works but I just can't seem to see how these negative coords and wrapping fit in.